# Winmerge - block as a single difference

Tags: winmerge

Please have a look at the screen shot below:

[image: WinMerge screen shot]

Why is the following Text highlighted yellow: This is a Test2.  The text appears in both files.

I have found a quote from the following website: http://manual.winmerge.org/Intro_diffs.html.  The quote is: "it's also useful to treat an entire block of lines as a single difference".  Therefore I am wandering if a block is being treated as a single difference.  Where is this configured?

Comment: Does Test2.txt finish with `'2'` or `'\n'`?

Comment: @azhrei, it finishes with a 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinMerge compares by lines, and treats a block of lines that have differences as a single difference. You don't configure that, per se. That's not your problem.

Your problem is that Test2.txt doesn't finish with a carriage return.

So WinMerge compares `This is a Test2\r\n` with `This is a Test2<eof>` and these are different.

(And note how WinMerge treats the rest of the lines in Test1.txt as 'a single difference').

*Confirmed with WinMerge 2.14.0.0*

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. +1.could you confirm what you mean by: "a single difference"?

Comment: Sure - just trying to address what you thought the problem might be, about WinMerge treating a block of lines as a single difference. I've added more detail in the answer.